# LINQ Query Order by Month name non-alphabetically

Tags: entity-framework, linq

How do I order this query by month not alphabetically? I have two columns in my db. One for the month name and one for month number.

Right now it orders months alphabetically.

```
var querythpmsick = (from r in db.SickLeaveRequestForms
                            where r.EmployeeID == id
                             group r by r.MonthOfHoliday into g
                            select new { Value = g.Key, Count1 = g.Sum(h => h.SickLeaveTaken) }
                           ).OrderBy(e => e.Value);
```

Comment: Have you considered using the month *number* rather than the name, in the database? I'd expect that to be significantly more useful in all ways.

Comment: @JonSkeet well I have both in there atm. Its not a overly large db so I figured it was okay

Comment: Well then group by the numeric version instead of the name.

Comment: I done that too, but I need to display it by month name not number, would there be a way to do this? This is also being used for a google chart

Comment: Just transform the number to a name when you provide the data to Google charts. It's trivial to go from month number to month name, after all.

Comment: "I have both in there atm. Its not a overly large db so I figured it was okay". Nope, multiple sources of truth. Some day, some code will responsible for Month = 3 and MonthOfHoliday = "January". Name isn't as useful as #, and it is a display concern, not a data concern. I'd recommend dropping the name from the database and having your client code/viewmodel resolve the name from the number when needed. Storing the name is also not localizable. Those pesky Frenchmen insist on Noël in décembre.

Answer (score 0):

If you have both the month name and the month number in your DB, then just group by the number instead of the month name:

```
var querythpmsick = (from r in db.SickLeaveRequestForms where r.EmployeeID == 2
                            group r by r.MonthOfHolidayInt into g
                            select new { Value = g.Key, Count1 = g.Sum(h => h.SickLeaveTaken), MonthName = g.Select(d => d.MonthOfHoliday) })
                                     .OrderBy(e => e.Value);
```

Here is a DotNetFiddle with the example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6vE4lo